# JetBrains IDEs scrolling on touchscreen

Tags: ide, phpstorm, pycharm, touchscreen

I'm having a problem scrolling in all the JetBrains IDEs (PyCharm, PhpStorm) using touch screen. I have a Dell XPS 15 with a touchscreen.

When I try to scroll it just selects code. I have tried in regular Notepad and Notepad++ and there works as expected.

Has anyone else experienced it? Is there any solution to this? It would be really great to scroll through the code using touchscreen.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95774 -- I guess this is the root ticket to look after.

Comment: It does not work for me too. I use keyboard shortcuts(ctrl+up, ctrl+down).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found temporary solution by installing plugin Code glance (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275). The plugin provides a sidebar with code map, which is similar to the one from Sublime. In the sidebar it is possible to navigate through code. It is not ideal but it's better than nothing.

Comment: This is the best solution for now.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I was having the same problem. And luckily I got a gesture to scroll using two fingers:

**Scroll up**: Tap and hold using one finger and swipe away[from close to distant of the first finger] using another finger. Swiping away from each other also works.

**Scroll Down**: Tap and hold using one finger and swipe in[from distant to close of the first finger] using another finger. Swiping close to each other also works.

[image: Scrolling up-down in jetbrains IDE]